# Meteor: Race Condition Trouble Using richsilv:owl-carousel with Template {{#each}} Contents

Tags: meteor, owl-carousel

I seem to be having some trouble with Meteor 1.0.3.2 in conjunction with richsilv:owl-carousel and MongoDB collections.

I'll list the code below, but the upshot is that when using {{#each}} inside the richsilv:owl-carousel div, an intermittent number of items will appear outside, specifically, before the carousel. I mention a race condition as the number of outside items will vary upon refresh.

The carousel template looks like this:

```
<template name="someStuffCarousel">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
   {{> theStuff}}
  </div>
</template>
```

theStuff template is:

```
<template name="theStuff">
{{#each something}}
  <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; width: 33%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="headingOne" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">{{title}}</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">{{description}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

The carousel coffeescript file is (the collection is declared and published elsewhere and autopublish has been disabled):

```
somethingSubscribe = Meteor.subscribe('somethingPublish')

Template.someStuffCarousel.rendered = ->
    Tracker.autorun(((computation) ->               
            if somethingSubscribe.ready()
                    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()
                    computation.stop()
            ).bind(this))
```

Not listed above is the 'something' helper. The data from the collection is being propagated to the client, but some of the rendering is still happening outside of the carousel div, presumably, before 'somethingSubscribe.ready()' fires.

Overall, I think I'm seeing a race condition where the 'theStuff' template {{#each}} iteration is partially firing before subscription 'ready' event does. My understanding was that using the 'ready' event would ensure that that *didn't* happen.

I seem to have missed something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this one out.

The basic problem was caused by using the {{#each}} block in the template and not populating the carousel solely via its api. This led to the race condition that resulted in an intermittent number of "theStuff" being rendered outside the carousel div.

The new carousel template looks like this:

```
<template name="someStuffCarousel">

 <div class="owl-carousel">

 </div>

</template>
```

The new stuff template is thus:

```
<template name="theStuff">
  <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"      class="panel-group" style="margin-bottom: 1cm; width: 33%; margin-left:  auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div id="headingOne" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">{{title}}</a>
    </h4>
     </div>
     <div id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"  class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">{{description}}</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And lastly, the programmatic rendering coffeescript is:

```
somethingSubscribe = Meteor.subscribe('somethingPublish')

Template.someStuffCarousel.rendered = ->

    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()

    Tracker.autorun(((computation) ->

            if somethingSubscribe.ready()
                    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()

                    somethings = getSomethings()    // just a standard 'get data' function

                    somethings.forEach((something) ->

                            $(".owl-carousel").data("owl-carousel").addItem(Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.theStuff, something))
                    )
            ).bind(this))
```